# Android app crashing (looper = null)

Tags: android, android-service, android-2.2-froyo, looper

I have a problem with my app. My application is actually a service. I have Main extends Service, it has private Looper looper variable to get HandlerThread looper. In `onCreate` function I initialize location manager, location listener and HandlerThread (which sets its looper to looper variable), then I try to use `requestLocationUpdates` passing the looper variable as looper. I gets an error

```
09-22 17:30:24.069: E/AndroidRuntime(1414): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: looper==null
```

Should I do anything else to this HandlerThread? Maybe start it?:>

I don't paste any code since it's quite long and I don't know the relevant part which would be appropriate to solve the problem. Therefore I'd love to pass any code You may need (HandlerThread? Anything else?)

Thanks for any help.

** EDIT ********

Alright, onCreate function:

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d("Service", "Service onCreate starts");
    running = true;
    lt = new LooperThread("GPSIntentLT");
    serviceLocationM = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    serviceLocationL = new MyLocationListener();

    requestUpdates(serviceLocationL);
    Log.d("Service", "Service onCreate ends");
}
```

requestUpdates function (called above, there the error appears):

```
private void requestUpdates(LocationListener listener)
{
    Log.d("Service", "requestUpdates starts");
    serviceLocationM.removeUpdates(listener);
    flag = displayGpsStatus();
    switch(flag)
    {
    case 0:
        Log.d("Service", "No Location Provider");
        break;
    case 1:
        Log.d("Service", "Network Provider");
        serviceLocationM.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 10, 25, listener, theLooper);
        break;
    case 2:
        Log.d("Service", "GPS Provider");
        serviceLocationM.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10, 25, listener, theLooper);
        break;
    }
    Log.d("Service", "requestUpdates ends");
}
```

And HandlerThread:

```
private class LooperThread extends HandlerThread{

    public LooperThread(String name) {
        super(name);
        Log.d("Service", "LooperThread constructor starts");
        theLooper = getLooper();
        Log.d("Service", "LooperThread constructor ends");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        Log.d("Service", "LooperThread run called");
    }

}
```

And at the end, logcat for this app:

```
09-22 18:21:47.997: D/Service(386): Service onCreate starts
09-22 18:21:47.997: D/Service(386): LooperThread constructor starts
09-22 18:21:48.007: D/Service(386): LooperThread constructor ends
```

So it does go down on requestLocationUpdates function, it happens on 2.2 emulator, on 2.3.3 it crashes the whole emulator by killing its processes (?).

Comment: You should at least post what code you can of the classes, onCreate, and the handler thread.

Comment: Why are you extending a HandlerThread?

Comment: To get its looper :> This is what I've been told as an answer to my last question. Is there any other way to do so? (I need to keep my app persistent/looped, so it picks up location every 5~ minutes and do something with it).

Comment: call ht = new HandlerThread(); ht.start(); handler = new Handler(ht.getLooper())

Comment: how do I pass this handler to my requestLocationUpdates then?:>

Comment: Ok, in your case you dont need a handler, just pass ht.getLooper()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html#getLooper%28%29

> This method returns the Looper associated with this thread. If this thread not been started or for any reason is isAlive() returns false, this method will return null. If this thread has been started, this method will block until the looper has been initialized.

Since you call this method in the constructor of the LooperThread, then of course you have not started it yet (by calling `start()`).
The method returns null, which in itself is valid, and the constructor completes, but then you pass null later on in `requestUpdates()`, which causes the crash.

You will need to start the thread and then acquire a reference to the looper. Make sure it is ready before trying to use it in another method.

Comment: Alright, seems rational, I did what You said - I get error message

    `Only one looper may be created per thread`

I do not create any loopers, just initialize this handlerthread and get its looper. I will add that I have lt.run() after initializing it, but it never goes into that function.

Comment: This sounds like more of a separate issue, search the error on this site. And I corrected my answer to use start() instead of run().

Comment: well, `start()` instead of `run()` fixed the error. It also work (getting the location). Could You possibly tell me why function `onStatusChanged` is called on my LocationListener every time my app uses `onLocationChanged`?? Is it normal? I thought it is called only when provider changes its status :>

Comment: I don't know much about this - perhaps because you are calling removeUpdates(listener)

Comment: Ok, I will try to figure this out myself. Thanks really much!